# File upload in PHP: Validating that a file is gpx

Tags: php, security, file-upload, gpx

I am currently working on a project where the users can upload images and GPX files. No problem in validating the images but I simply can't find a secure way to make sure that the gpx files are not some malicious file instead. 
Any hints are very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Edit: Can anyone please point out why this code is not working? By not working I mean that it does not reject PDF files.

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
if (!$xml->xml($_FILES["gps"]["tmp_name"], NULL, LIBXML_DTDVALID)) {
    echo '<script>alert("Not valid!");</script>';           
    exit();
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is checking the [file headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: GPX should be valid XML? easy to check that

Comment: gpx is xml, isn't it? load the file into a DOM Validator and feed it the GPX DTDs for comparison.

Comment: Xerxes GPX parser could do it: http://www.topografix.com/gpx_validation.asp

Comment: Yes, GPX is XML. Will try the DOM Validator! Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.isvalid.php

Comment: Also pass only valid extensions, jpeg and gpx for example.

Comment: @VG: Extensions don't really mean much.  Files can renamed.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, GPX is XML.  So just load it into an XML parser and make sure it has a `<gpx>` tag.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Extensions mean much if files are saved. What if someone upload a php/js/py/pl or other executables. This is security reason mostly.

Comment: @VG: True.  But, it's better to check if it's a valid image/xml more so than just the extension.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Definitely always need to check both extension and content. The question was about malicious uploaded files too.

Comment: I am obviously doing something wrong. This code does allow me to upload pdf for example: $xml = new XMLReader();
 if (!$xml->xml($_FILES["gps"]["tmp_name"], NULL, LIBXML_DTDVALID)) {
  echo '<script>alert("Not valid!");</script>';   
  exit();
 }

Comment: @Dagon … until someone uploads a valid GPX file containing PHP code as `.php`.

Comment: @Gumbo thanks for stalking me, i feel special now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xmlcontents = XMLReader::open($_FILES["gps"]["tmp_name"]);

$xmlcontents->setParserProperty(XMLReader::VALIDATE, true);

if($xmlcontents->isValid() and ($xml->xml($_FILES["gps"]["tmp_name"], NULL, LIBXML_DTDVALID))) {
}
else {
    echo 'Not a valid GPS file!")';            
    exit();
}
```

note here you check the file validity as xml , and it's extention
try this